# Does not contain a definition for 'ProjectTo'

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I am trying to use automapper with a generic repository and I get the following error:

```
'Task<IEnumerable<Category>>' does not contain a definition for 'ProjectTo' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.ProjectTo<IEnumerable<CategoryResponse>>(IQueryable, IConfigurationProvider, params Expression<Func<IEnumerable<CategoryResponse>, object>>[])' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'
```

This is in the repository

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This is in the controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories()
    {
        var c = await _unitOfWork.CategoryRepositoryAsync.GetAllAsync()
            .ProjectTo<IEnumerable<CategoryResponse>>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        return Ok(c);
    }
```

I am quite new netcore and the automapper isn't like I used to work with a while ago. I am sure this is a dumb question but please bare with my learning process.

Comment: Have you tried `(await _unitOfWork.CategoryRepositoryAsync.GetAllAsync()).ProjectTo(...)`?

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the repo

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntityProject>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ProjectTo<TEntityProject>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I just don't like it because I needed to add another generic to the repository but I guess it will work for now, building just the scheleton and a few crud operations.

```
    public class Repository<TEntity, TEntityProject> : IRepositoryAsync<TEntity, TEntityProject> where TEntity: class
                                                                                             where TEntityProject:class
```

So of course I had to change everything where it did break and the impact is that I will need to be careful how I am using those generics types depending on POST or GET

Controller code is like this for now:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories()
    {
        var c = await _unitOfWork.CategoryRepositoryAsync.GetAllAsync();

        return Ok(c);
    }
```

Everything works, problem solved. But I may ask some more experienced net developers, can be this a long term solution?